# Would asterisk questions be welcome here?

Tags: discussion, migration

Is it ok if I vote to migrate [asterisk](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asterisk) questions from Super User to here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, since Asterix is extremely sysadmin-y -- are there any questions about Asterix that are actually end-user type things?

Also, how many are we talking?

Comment: It's 13 of them.

Comment: @Nifle, If it's from an Admin's prospective then probably yes. If it's from a users' prospective (As Robert Moir pointed out) then no.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely, just like Exchange, SQL Server, Oracle, DNS servers, etc., etc. These are very much admin things.

Answer (score 3):

I think when its admin related (e.g. how do I set up Asterisk, how do I configure it to talk to...) then clearly it belongs here. If it's end user related (e.g. what kewl things can I do with this phone plugged into a Asterisk VoIP system) then maybe SU isn't the right place for it but neither is SF.

Answer (score 2):

This question looks off-topic for serverfault.  If you look at the text, the person specifically mentions that he doesn't really want a sysadmin response.  It possibly should have just been closed.

- https://superuser.com/questions/124118/what-are-some-potential-uses-of-asterisk-pbx-for-a-power-user-closed

I was going to try to vote to return that particular question, but I seem to be experiencing a bug.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74173/unable-to-select-vote-to-close

Serverfault isn't as busy as other sites.  I am somewhat surprised that you only waited only an hour or two after asking this question, before you actually performed the migrate.  It sure seems like you could have been a bit more patient.

Comment: Well when Jeff said it was probably OK I asked one of our moderators to do it. And it was only 13 of them.

Comment: @Nifle, questions that are obviously from an end user should be on SuperUser.