# Is serverfault the most suitable stack exchange site for Asterisk questions?

Tags: discussion

Is serverfault the most suitable stack exchange site for Asterisk questions?

I am using the unix & linux stack exchange a fair bit (it is easier to answer questions on it ;) but as asterisk is platform independent, would this site be a better place for it?

I am new to the community, so am trying to get my head around the differences between the stack exchange sites

I see a similar question was asked here, from this I take it that this is the best forum?

[Would asterisk questions be welcome here?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1058/would-asterisk-questions-be-welcome-here)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as Asterisk is being used in a business setting and your have administrative prilidge over Asterisk and everything it's connected to, yes Server Fault would be appropriate.

The main difference between SF and the others like SU and Unix.SE is that SF requires you to be a System Administrator (et al) and the Question be related to your professional capacity (your job). The other sites are for enthusiasts or anyone who can put a coherent question together. All of them have a [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq); please take a moment to at least breeze through the first section of each; we spent quite a bit of time trying to perfect ours.

The main reason for this separation is that the relatively few people who really know their stuff get very tired of the millions of inquisitive idiots (that might be a harsh term, but it's well earned historically). There's little guarantee that you'll get a correct or quality answer on SU or Unix.SE (the latter tends to be better because of the limited focus). I'd like to think SF has higher quality on account of the limited scope and limited audience (which I have generally found to be true).

Comment: I would add that *research for your job* is generally on-topic here -- for example if you have set up an Asterisk development lab (a couple of servers with a SIP or IAX trunk between them, and a couple of IP phones) and you're trying to debug some funky behavior that would be OK, as long as you're doing it so Office A and Office B can communicate on one phone network, as opposed to so you can talk to Aunt Gertie using VOIP...

Comment: That's great,  I've recently had the administration of a asterisk phone system landed on my desk so it would definitely come under the heading of _research_! thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Roomey Assuming you're actually USING the system that falls squarely in the realm of "production system support". "Research" is when you haven't deployed it yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Right now I think SF is the most appropriate place for such questions. If/when "Telophony" gets off the ground that may become the better site, depending I believe entirely on the question context.

Comment: the "Telophony.SE" area 51 was closed at the start of May as a duplicate of ServerFault.

Comment: That's a pity. I though that question had been more than satisfactorily addressed here in favour of it *not* being a dupe of SF. It never fails to amaze me which sites get started and which ones get snuffed out, and why. There's some real absurdities amongst them.